# Posting ScrollView Content on FaceBook wall

Tags: android, facebook, scrollview

I used ScrollView in my application. It contains a LinearLayout as child and some other views likes 
TextViews,Buttons etc... as sub-views. Now I want to post the content of scrollview as an image on FaceBook wall.I could not find out a suitable  post.

```
   **My question is how to post ScrollView/Layout content on facebook wall?...**
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: first convert your view in to bitmap image and then post on facebook

Comment: look at my answer how to convert a view in to bitmap image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function to convert your view in to bitmap image

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 640,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

then post bitmap image on facebook wall

hope help you..

Comment: Thanks Deepak.This code works.But it does not show entire content of ScrollView.Only shows the content at specified width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I changed above code to

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                  view.getMeasuredHeight() , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
            return returnedBitmap;
}
```

It works fine and got bitmap of all content.